# Python secret santa-ish draw

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Sometimes it works fine, sometimes throws an error. Cannot figure it out. No matter how many inputs.

Thats the error. Is it the order of the code or something else?

```
    give_gift.remove(reciever)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Code:

```
import random
import os
import time
random.seed()
buy_gift = []
give_gift = []
names = True
print('Add name, then press ENTER. To finish type "end".')
while names is True:
    name = input()
    if name == "end":
        if len(buy_gift) < 2:
            print("Go play with your own gift. Goodbye!")
            print()
            os.system("PAUSE")
            quit()
        else:
            names = False
    else:
        buy_gift.append(name)
        give_gift.append(name)

exchange = len(give_gift)
os.system("cls")
time.sleep(1)
print("Drawing pairs...")
print()
time.sleep(1)
while exchange > 0:
    giver = random.choice(buy_gift)
    reciever = random.choice(give_gift)
    while giver == reciever:
        reciever = random.choice(buy_gift)
    print(giver,"buys gift for",reciever)
    time.sleep(0.25)
    buy_gift.remove(giver)
    give_gift.remove(reciever)
    exchange -= 1
print()
os.system("PAUSE")
```

Comment: Hi. Try to add a little bit more information to the question. What is it supposed to be doing? What is it doing instead? What error does it produce? Without this information, it's really hard to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't seem to have anything in place to prevent a situation where the last giver and the last receiver are the same person.

Comment: Also you re-draw receivers from the giver list.

Comment: But I'd like to understand why after few successful draws it just hangs up.

Comment: "You don't seem to have anything in place to prevent a situation where the last giver and the last receiver are the same person."

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with this line:

```
while giver == reciever:
    reciever = random.choice(buy_gift)
```

It should be:

```
reciever = random.choice(give_gift)
```